# Remove Characters From List in Python

Tags: python, list

I have a list : `lst = [('asd'),('fgb'),('tre'),...]` like this . I want to remove "(" and ")" characters . The result must be : `['asd','fgb','tre',...]`

Comment: The result already is `['asd','fgb','tre'...` unless you have a string and not actually a list

Answer (score 2):

Note that `()` around a string is just a syntactic sugar in python, which has no literal meaning.

Example:

```
>>> 'asd' == ('asd')
True
```

If you really want to fix this, one way would be:

```
>>> x = [('asd'),('fgb'),('tre')]
>>> x
['asd', 'fgb', 'tre']
>>> xx = [i for i in x]
>>> xx
['asd', 'fgb', 'tre']
```

But it does not really make any difference in the way python would parse the list

Comment: Or just `x`; list's repr method shouldn't know about the parenthesis.

Comment: True, but i have a feeling this might not actually be a string generated by the interpreter. .

Comment: `[i for i in x]` does not actually do anything.

Comment: Exactly, and i did mention that in the answer

Answer (score 1):

If your list looks exactly like you posted it, then the parentheses do nothing, so there are none to remove:

```
>>> [('asd'),('fgb'),('tre')]
['asd', 'fgb', 'tre']
```

I am assuming that the parentheses are actually part of your strings (you probably misplaced the quotation marks) and that you only want the ones at the start and the beginning of a string in your list removed:

```
>>> lst = ['(asd)', '(fgb)', '(tre)']
>>> [x[1:-1] for x in lst]
['asd', 'fgb', 'tre']
```

Otherwise, if you want to remove *all* parentheses you can use `re`:

```
>>> [re.sub('\)|\(', '', s) for s in lst]
['asd', 'fgb', 'tre']
```

or chain `str.replace`

```
>>> [s.replace('(', '').replace(')', '') for s in lst]
['asd', 'fgb', 'tre']
```